# how to Query semi structure data from snowflake stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-connector

I have a file format like this:

```
create or replace file format parq1 type='PARQUET';
```

I have a parquet file in stage sampleparquet and able to querying it in the below way:

```
select $1 from @sampleparquet (file_format=>parq1 );
```

If I try to querying it in the below way I am not getting any data(getting a sql compilation error):

1. select $1 from @sampleparquet (file_format=>(type='PARQUET'));
2. select $1 from @sampleparquet (file_format= parq1 );

Kindly suggest the reason behind it in snowflake

Comment: The syntax **file_format=>(type='PARQUET')** is not supported for the SELECT statement, aren't you getting an error?

Comment: getting an error "sql compilation error:invalid argument.."

Comment: `type = parquet` not `type = 'parquet'` I do not believe you need quotes around it in your file format.  Might be causing your issue.

Comment: Mike Walton , I have tried type = parquet and no luck and getting same error

Answer (score 1):

The syntax:

```
select $1 from @sampleparquet (file_format=>(type='PARQUET'));
```

is not supported as per our [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html).

You will have to use this format:

```
select $1 from @sampleparquet (file_format=>parq1 );
```